# redirect all urls with "videos.php" to base

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm hoping someone can assist me with a mod_rewrite rule to redirect dynamic urls pointing to "videos.php" on my server to the base url.

For example, I need to redirect 'website.com/1/music/various/videos.php?=1234'
to 'website.com/videos.php?=1234'

edit: I am looking for a dynamic solution. If a url is pointed to videos.php at any time, I need to do a 301 redirect to home directory. Ie if /1/home/music/videos.php?=1234 redirect to /videos.php?=1234, or /music/playlist/1234/videos.php?1432 to /videos.php?1432.

Comment: not yet, i've done a bit of research. I'm new to mod_rewrite rules and I'm unsure of how to match the dynamic urls. One url may be 'website.com/1/music/various/videos.php' while another is 'website.com/1/music/newmusic/videos.php'. I need a rule that will rewrite all to base. I am familiar with how to rewrite the specefic url, but I need a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file and insert these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Page moved permanently:
RewriteRule ^videos\.php\?\=([0-9]+)\.html$ /1/music/various/videos.php?=$1 [R=301,L]
```

When testing, leave out the `R=301,` part, or you'll only see cache contents for a long, long time. Add it when sure its working fine. Or use 302, which means temporarily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks about right. however, I'll need to rewrite any url containing videos.php to home directory ie /music/1234/videos.php to /videos.php or /1/home/videos.php to /videos.php.

Comment: Your original question did not mention that.
Since that tweak is so easy, i urge you to first look at a mod_rewrite cheatsheet such as http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/ and give it a go yourself first. You might learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/1/music/various/videos.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /videos.php [R,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/videos.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301]
```

If it's not work, then try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/1/music/various/videos.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /videos.php%1 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/videos.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301]
```